# Not able to run an exe in jenkins pipeline using powershell

Tags: powershell, jenkins, exe, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am trying to execute a process which is written in c# through jenkins pipeline during the build and deployment process.

It is a simple executable which takes 3 arguments, when it gets called from jenkins pipeline using a powershell function it doesn't write any logs which are plenty within the code of this exe, also it does not show anything on the pipeline logs as to what happened to this process. Whereas the logs output is clean before and after the execution of this process i.e. "Started..." & "end" gets printed in the jenkins build log.

When i try to run the same exe on a server directly with the same powershel script it runs perfectly fine. Could you please let me know how can i determine whats going wrong here or how can i make the logs more verbose so i can figure out the root cause.

Here is the code snippet

build-utils.ps1

```
function disable-utility($workspace) {
    #the code here fetches the executable and its supporting libraries from the artifactory location and unzip it on the build agent server.
    #below is the call to the executable
    Type xmlPath #this prints the whole contents of the xml file which is being used as an input to my exe.
    echo "disable exe path exists : $(Test-Path ""C:\Jenkins\workspace\utils\disable.exe"")" // output is TRUE
    echo "Started..."
    Start-Process -NoNewWindow -Filepath "C:\Jenkins\workspace\utils\disable.exe" -ArgumentList "-f xmlPath 0"  #xmlPath is a path to a xml file
    echo "end."
}
```

jenkinsfile

```
library {
    identifier: 'jenkins-library@0.2.14',
    retriever: legacySCM{[
      $class: 'GitSCM',
      userRemoteConfigs: [[
        credtialsId: 'BITBUCKET_RW'
        url: <htps://gitRepoUrl>
      ]]
    ]}
}

def executeStep(String stepName) {
   def butil = '.\\build\\build-utils.ps1'
   if(fileExists(butil)) 
   {
     def status = powershell(returnStatus: true, script: "& { . '${butil}'; ${stepName}; }")
     echo status
     if(status != 0) {
       currentBuild.Result = 'Failure'
       error("$StepName failed")           
     }
   }
   else 
   {
     error("failed to find the file")
   }
}

pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image '<path to the docker image to pull a server with VS2017 build tools>'
      lable '<image name>'
      reuseNode true
    }
  }
  environment {
    #loading the env variables here
  }
  stages {
    stage {
      step {
        executeStep("disable-utility ${env.workspace}")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: can you try replace `Start-Process` line with the following `cmd /c "C:\Jenkins\workspace\utils\disable.exe" -f xmlPath 0` ? See if this works...

Comment: I tried the above and got an error in the pipeline stage where the status returned from powershell shows the value = '1073741515' (without any other errors in the pipeline logs) , with the Start-Process the code was exiting with a '0' but the results is same , i.e. not executing anything.

Comment: @Siddharth - your solution again works on a standalone server when tried but gives the error when tried through the pipeline. Is there any way we can make the logs more verbose to find out what is going wrong with the script. Thanks!

Comment: well i am not sure. What can be done is see if disable.exe executes at all by redirecting output to a text file. Something like this `cmd /c "C:\Jenkins\workspace\utils\disable.exe" -f xmlPath 0 > debug.txt`. You can see if the text file is generated at all...

Comment: Tried this and there are no logs produced. There's a correction I would like to make here is that the exe is not a C# one but its written in C++, On trying out more things i tried to install VC++ runtimes and IBM Symphony Platform Symphony as it may be a dependency but still the issue persists. Unable to find whats going wrong when we are triggering the exe.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed it ? go to Regedit [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System Set "EnableLUA"= 0

Comment: What do you mean here ? I am doing all this on jenkins build agent and the agent control is not in my hands.